# Why won't my Index/Match start at the top of the worksheet?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a list of names in a drop down in `A1`.  I have a formula that looks at the text selected, it matches that text on another worksheet, and then displays a list of ID numbers found next to that name.  This formula outputs my results to the corresponding row that this text and ID are found in on the other worksheet. So I may have the id in row 3, 7, & 12, or even a clump in 15, 16, & 17.

I have attempted `vlookup`, but with no unique identifier its all the same result.

I found this formula online that I thought I may could modify to my uses, and I could get it to display a number in `A2` that was usually further down the page, but I haven't been able to make it work beyond that.

```
=OFFSET($A$1,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$28=$D$1,ROW($C$1:$C$28)-MIN(ROW($C$1:$C$28))+1),ROWS($1:1))-1,0)
```

My formula :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A2, MATCH($A$1, Data!$C2, 0))," ")
```

I need it to always output starting in cell `A2`, and consecutively work its way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the method you attempted using OFFSET could be made to work. Once I dug into it, I went another way. I'm sure it's not the most elegant, but it works.

I understand your request to be:

- Given an input in A1
- Given a sheet called Data containing a chart of ID strings in column A corresponding to data in column C to compare to the input in Sheet1!A1

You want to display each instance of the input in the data in cells A2 descending downwards?

[Like so?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9xR6.png)  EDIT: wrap with an IFERROR to eliminate the nasty N/A's that I forgot before I screenshotted

I was able to make this work given sample data:

```
001     random
002     words
003     sample
004     is
005     never
006     actually
007     random
008     actually
009     random
010     sample
011     words
012     are
013     not
014     easy
015     to
016     generate
017     random
018     words
019     actually
020     sample
021     sample
```

Formula in cell A2 (trivial):

```
=INDEX(Data!$A$1:$A$99, MATCH($A$1, Data!$C$1:$C$99, 0))
```

Cell A3:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Data!$A$"&MATCH(A2,Data!A:A,0)+1&":$A$99"), MATCH($A$1, INDIRECT("Data!$C"&MATCH(A2,Data!A:A,0)+1&":$C$99"), 0))
```

That formula copies down.

Note the assumption that the data source is no more than 99 rows.

I used `INDIRECT` function to redefine the range being searched by the n+1th search to search an array that starts from the row right after the result returned by the nth search. Not sure how scalable but it's better than having helper rows for as many rows as you have data, which is how I'd have approached this problem a year ago...

EDIT in re your comment reply - I undertook the answer based primarily on the last line of your question 'I need it to always output starting in cell A2, and consecutively work its way down.' that you *wanted* to see a column of cells with one ID per cell. I suppose that's open to interpretation. Rather than try to write one God Formula here I'd probably just write a formula in B1 to `CONCATENATE` the values in A2..An with commas in between, if you're looking for a single outputted list.

Comment: This has worked.  Thank you kindly! If you think of anyway that it can be a bit cleaner maybe in one shared formula that would be exciting.  Again thanks!

Comment: @JvdV thanks, I don't know what the technical classification of #N/A is but in my version of Excel it's included in IFERROR and ISERROR (though not ISERR)